# Adding Quantum State Tomography Step to HHL Algorithm (Cirq)

Tags: programming, cirq, hhl-algorithm, state-tomography

Over the past month, I have been learning about the HHL algorithm and am interested in extending the [Cirq implementation](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/examples/hhl.py) to include the quantum state tomography step to extract the amplitudes or solutions of $|x\rangle$. How would I do this in Cirq?

Thanks!

Comment: Bump! Does anyone have experience doing this in Cirq?